Docker build in Github Actions fails for node arm64 image
I am trying to build an image for my personal nodejs project to be run on my raspberry pi.
It's an arm64 node js build, but the build fails with this error:
#10 [5/5] RUN npm install
#10 0.154 exec /bin/sh: exec format error
#10 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c npm install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
------
 > [5/5] RUN npm install:
0.154 exec /bin/sh: exec format error
------
Dockerfile:9
--------------------
   7 |     COPY . .
   8 |     
   9 | >>> RUN npm install
  10 |     
  11 |     EXPOSE 3000
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

My Dockerfile looks like this:
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 arm64v8/node:20

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

COPY . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]

I have tried with multiple versions of node with the same result. I have also tried with a non-arm64 version of node (by mistake) which builded successfully, so it must be something with the arm64 version.
What could I be missing?

Please try run npm install with --verbose. Then you can see what the error is.

I got it working!
The Github Action script was building for the wrong architecture. Changed to buildx
- name: Set up Docker Buildx
      uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

- name: Build the Docker image
      run: |
         docker buildx create --use
         docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 \
         -f backend/Dockerfile \
         -t ghcr.io/${{ github.repository_owner }}/budgetapp-backend:${{ env.NEW_VERSION }} \
         --push \
         ./backend


What was the wrong architecture?
